# Pandas interpolation method definitions

Tags: pandas, scipy, interpolation

In the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html), a number of methods are provided as arguments to `pandas.DataFrame.interpolate` including

> nearest’, ‘zero’, ‘slinear’, ‘quadratic’, ‘cubic’, ‘spline’, ‘barycentric’, ‘polynomial’: Passed to scipy.interpolate.interp1d. These methods use the numerical values of the index. Both ‘polynomial’ and ‘spline’ require that you also specify an order (int), e.g. df.interpolate(method='polynomial', order=5).

> ‘krogh’, ‘piecewise_polynomial’, ‘spline’, ‘pchip’, ‘akima’, ‘cubicspline’: Wrappers around the SciPy interpolation methods of similar names. See Notes

However, the [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) indicates the following options:

> kind str or int, optional
> Specifies the kind of interpolation as a string or as an integer specifying the order of the spline interpolator to use. The string has to be one of ‘linear’, ‘nearest’, ‘nearest-up’, ‘zero’, ‘slinear’, ‘quadratic’, ‘cubic’, ‘previous’, or ‘next’. ‘zero’, ‘slinear’, ‘quadratic’ and ‘cubic’ refer to a spline interpolation of zeroth, first, second or third order; ‘previous’ and ‘next’ simply return the previous or next value of the point; ‘nearest-up’ and ‘nearest’ differ when interpolating half-integers (e.g. 0.5, 1.5) in that ‘nearest-up’ rounds up and ‘nearest’ rounds down. Default is ‘linear’.

The documentation seems wrong since `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` does not accept `barycentric` or `polynomial` as valid methods.  I suppose that `barycentric` refers to `scipy.interpolate.barycentric_interpolate`, but what does `polynomial` refer to?  I thought it might be equivalent to the `piecewise_polynomial` option, but the two give different results.

Also, `method=cubicspline` and `method=spline, order=3` give different results.  What's the difference here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pandas` interpolate method is an amalgamation of interpolation methods coming from different places in the `numpy` and `scipy` libraries.

Currently all of the code is located in [`pandas/core/missing.py`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.0/pandas/core/missing.py).

At a high level it [splits the interpolation](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.0/pandas/core/missing.py#L124-L145) methods into those that are handled by `np.iterp` and others handled by throughout the `scipy` library.

```
# interpolation methods that dispatch to np.interp
NP_METHODS = ["linear", "time", "index", "values"]

# interpolation methods that dispatch to _interpolate_scipy_wrapper
SP_METHODS = ["nearest", "zero", "slinear", "quadratic", "cubic",
              "barycentric", "krogh", "spline", "polynomial",
              "from_derivatives", "piecewise_polynomial", "pchip",
              "akima", "cubicspline"]
```

Then because the `scipy` methods are split across different methods, you can see there are a ton of other wrappers within `missing.py` that indicate the scipy method. Most of the methods are passed off to `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`; however for a few others there's a [dict](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.0/pandas/core/missing.py#L462-L468) or other wrapper methods pointing to those specific `scipy` methods.

```
from scipy import interpolate

alt_methods = {
    "barycentric": interpolate.barycentric_interpolate,
    "krogh": interpolate.krogh_interpolate,
    "from_derivatives": _from_derivatives,
    "piecewise_polynomial": _from_derivatives,
}
```

where the doc string of `_from_derivatives` within `missing.py` indicates:

```
def _from_derivatives(xi, yi, x, order=None, der=0, extrapolate=False):
    """
    Convenience function for interpolate.BPoly.from_derivatives.
    ...
    """
```

---

So TLDR, depending upon the method you specify you wind up directly using one of the following:

```
numpy.interp
scipy.interpolate.interp1d
scipy.interpolate.barycentric_interpolate
scipy.interpolate.krogh_interpolate
scipy.interpolate.BPoly.from_derivatives
scipy.interpolate.Akima1DInterpolator
scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline
scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline
```